# Program does not run after switching from VS2013 to VS2015

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, wix, .net-4.6

I have a solution which contains 5 C# projecst, 2 wix projects and a C project (2010). We have been developing this in VS2013 Ultimate and all has been fine. I've just tried opening the solution in VS2015, I have no errors, and no warnings. When I press the start button (F5), nothing happens. I don't even hit the first line of the Program.cs file. All it seems to do is build the project. Any ideas?

EDIT

The same project was open in both VS2013 and VS2015 at the same time as I was comparing config etc.

When I closed down VS2013, the program ran!

Not entirely sure why this occurred...

Comment: Check if one of your solution projects marked as startup project (it has boll name in solution explorer). If none is marked, do it via context menu on right mousebutton click.

Comment: I have checked that, I do have a project marked and it is the correct project! @AndyKorneyev

Comment: in the project properties, there must be some startup object thing. check that it is set to something correct.

Comment: The properties for the start up project are identical to that of the same project in VS2013 @FarhanAnam

Comment: Just thought of something, is it possible it is not running because I have both VS2013 and VS2015 open?

Comment: no that should not be the cause.

Comment: @FarhanAnam believe it or not, I just closed VS2013 and then my project loaded! Not sure what that means the cause is.

Comment: Does it run if you click the start "green play button"? Maybe your keyboard mappings have changed are they are no longer associated to F5. Also do you see something on the output window?

Comment: start it again and try openning the project.]

Comment: @Juan Yes I did try that and it didn't run either

Comment: If the project is open in both VS 2013 and 2015. It could be that one process uses a file that the other cannot access. However, if that was the case some errors must have popped up.

Comment: @FarhanAnam very interesting! No errors at all! No messages or anything, very strange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the problem is indeed with running the same project in both Visual Studio 2013 and 2015 at the same time.

When you start the program, only the version of VS which was opened first will be able to run the program. This is because the first opened VS attaches the `vshost.exe` process to the project and denies any access to that exe, which is why the last opened version fails to attach its own `vshost.exe`. Thus it stops after building the solution.

Comment: Thank-you @FarhanAnam !

Answer (score 1):

The same project was open in both VS2013 and VS2015 at the same time as I was comparing config etc.

When I closed down VS2013, the program ran!

Not entirely sure why this occurred...